# Firefox didn't show address bar, then total loss of data

Tags: windows, firefox

Well, the problem starts here. Up until an hour ago everything was running smoothly with Firefox 23.0.1 on Windows XP. However, and suddenly, the address bar disappeared. It just isn't there.

Figuring it was a bug, I checked my other account and it turns out it has the bar, so I know it is local only to my user. I tried to **Customize** the bar, with no effort.

I skimmed the net for answers and, to my surprise, it seemed it was a common problem. It suggested to try something called **Restore default set** which I did. What it did was simply change the buttons, the buttons settings to a newer version (so from this I still had remnants of an older theme around).

I thought that the problem might have been due to some error in the profile. Since I had a backup done recently, I made a new backup, deleted the profile folder and replaced with the old one.

Now, as soon as I started Firefox, it seems as if everything started anew. I don't have any extras, although I have all extensions. The settings are ruined, having no history, bookmarks or download history, no saved cookies, login info, etcetera. There is significant information contained in Firefox that I need on a daily basis.

To sum up:

- **How to bring back the address bar?**
- **How to restore the previous settings, having a backup done?**

I would like solutions that are only about Firefox. I'm not willing to change the browser. Here's a picture of the current bar.

[image: The bar]

I used to have a forward and backwards button, not just the backwards. Afterwards the DownloadHelper icon, after the address bar, after the Homepage bar, after the search bar and after the download bar. The arrangement of those items I know how to do, I just can't add the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after clearing my mind a little with a walk, I did the following:

1. Rebooted the PC

   - After this, Firefox regained the address bar. The *why* I don't know, but I've had a series of problems where the best solution was rebooting the OS (and not just logging off then on).
2. Restored *properly* the profile

   - The reason my previous restore didn't work was because I compressed my *profile **folder*** and then I just decompressed with the option of creating a folder in the same name as the archive.
   - After analyzing the contents I found a duplicate folder inside the profile that hinted at this.
   - To fix this, I deleted the profile folder and then I decompressed the backup archive in the folder. That decompressed correctly.
3. Restored the forward / backward button (aka [Firefox 10: How to disable the "The forward button is now hidden until you navigate back" functionality?](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-PT/questions/916489)).

   - It was a question of reformatting the Navigation Bar to conform with the old settings, using the Customize dialog.

This is how the bar is now:

[image: End Result]